# Automatically create Outlook calendar entry upon receiving email with Zoom link

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar, zoom-meeting

So every week I'm getting an email that looks like this:

【2023/11/20 Zoom Information】

- ID: 123 4567 8901
- URL: https://zoom.us/j/12345678901?pwd=XYZ123XYZ123XYZ123XYZ123
- Password: 112233

(Disclaimer: The text above contains only placeholder values and not actual links/access credentials)

Is there a way to automatically create an Outlook calendar entry(appointment/meeting) upon receiving that email? I want the entry to have the Zoom link already entered in it and I also want to set the entry's date and time to be according to the date in the content of the email and the time to be at say, 8-9a.m.

Comment: Is the information different every time?

Comment: @Ramhound yes. The `ID`, `URL` and `Password` changes every single time but the sender is the same person.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Power Automate. You can extract the date with a Compose step like "concat(substring(triggerBody()?['body'], indexOf(triggerBody()?['body'], '【') + 1, 10), 'T08:00:00')".

Answer (score 1):

As i known, there is no way to automatically create an Outlook calendar entry from a Zoom link without any manual intervention. I'm afraid that you need the help of script or third-party add-ins.

Comment: Yes, but the question is, how do I automate this with a script? What tool should I use?

Comment: If Zoom doesn't have you might have to create your own.